# Can't scroll properly on my website

Tags: html, css, iframe, scroll

I'm having an issue with my website. What is happening is:

1. My goal is to scroll down (using mouse wheel) all the way down to, to the bottom of the page.
2. I do that, but about half way, I can't scroll anymore. I keep using the scroll wheel and it still won't go down.
3. I move my cursor a TINY TINY bit to the left, right, up or down and I can scroll again.

What might be causing an issue like this?

Comment: If you scroll down to that point where scroll doesn't work anymore ... DO NOT MOVE THE MOUSE (so that it doesn't work again), click right click and Inspect element, what element is there? I suspect it's something to do with the element the mouse is over at that point, which is capturing the scroll event.

Comment: you have iFrame tag on your question. Can you show some code ?

Comment: @manishkumar Yep, I'll put that up now since I know where the issue is (thanks to protozoid). Give me moment

Comment: @Protozoid can you give me a mini tutorial on this inspect element thing. I did it the first time and it was over my `<div id="Bk3"></div>`. So I removed it. I did it again then it put me somewhere else

Comment: @manishkumar apparently (according to expect element) this is the issue, but I can't find it in my own code `<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" class="vsc-initialized">`

Comment: Can you show us your code? Or can you expose your local project with something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)?